# Returning an argument from R to bash

Tags: r, bash

I have the following bash script in which an R script is called

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -x a=33   
declare -x b=1       
declare -x c=0

Rscript --vanilla MWE.R $a $b $c

echo $a $b $c
```

I want to modify the bash variables in the R script and return their modified values in the bash script because I am then passing the modified variables somewhere else. The R script is

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
args = commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)

Rb = as.numeric(args[2])
Rc = as.numeric(args[3])

Rb = Rb + 1
Rc = Rc + 1

args[2]=Rb
args[3]=Rc

print(c(args[1],args[2],args[3]))
```

However, the output of the `print` and `echo` respectively are:

```
[1] "33" "2"  "1" 
33 1 0
```

which shows that the new values aren't passed from R to bash. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `Rscript` does not allow environment variable manipulation you will need to capture the `R` output from the `bash` program.

One of the many possibilities is to use an [`array`](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_10_02.html):

```
#!/bin/bash

declare a=33   
declare b=1       
declare c=0

declare -a RESULT
RESULT=($(Rscript --vanilla MWE.R $a $b $c))

a=${RESULT[1]}
b=${RESULT[2]}
c=${RESULT[3]}
```

Comment: This wasn't in my initial question but I can't find a way to manipulate the results of the array - I can modify the question if it's best. I need to test if `c` equals 1 but everything I tried to convert the output to an integer has failed (and I have tried since you first answered!). It looks like whatever I try the quotation marks around the results  prevent me from any further manipulation and even something like `c=${RESULT[3]} | sed "s/\"//g"` doesn't help. Basically, `c` always seems to be `"1"` but never `1`.

Comment: OK, what are you trying to achieve? i mean, all the arithmetic manipulation will be inside the bash script?

Comment: if `c` is `"1"`I then want to be able to use it as a numeric for more calculations in the bash script but whatever I try to convert it into a numeric e.g. amongst many others `c=${RESULT[3]} | sed "s/\"//g"`, it doesn't work. It is considered as a character (I guess) no matter what I do.